# Android custom Button style

Tags: android, button, background, styles

how can I have a button style like this
[image]

it is a background image or what?
and how to have a single line in the middle?

Comment: I think it is a textview in linearlayout and given click event to linearlayouts

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle">

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello World" />

<LinearLayout style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="One" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Two" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code by Roman Nurik [here](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/2348305).